# C# Windows Service Memory Usage steadily increasing

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

I don't know if it is a problem but...

This is the main call inside a Windows service.
The lower level logs into a WebService, retrieves information and passes it up.

A timer is hitting the main call 4 times a minute.

Gen 2 heap size gradually increases . GC does its best so you end up with a sort of Saw Tooth memory consumption, but the gradient of the Saw Tooth is slowly upwards. Working Set and Private Bytes also increase.
LOH size however is consistent.

The culprit appears to be System. Byte[].

ANTS Memory Profiler shows no linkage shown to any program objects. i.e. The retention Graphs only mention System objects.

The Profiler shows 60 % being held by *System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentStack,T> + Node* The other 40% is divided amongst other system classes.

I have refactored until I am blue in the face. Behavior seems consistent, making me think that perhaps it is not a problem but expected behavior.

If I return before the marked assignment the memory consumption is 'correct' like wise if I return immediately after the assignment the consumption is 'faulty'

So...
It is a real problem and if so any suggestions on what to do would be welcome.

```
 public  void GetItsValues()
    {
        using (Dt dt = new Dt())
        {

            List<ItsSite> siteList = dt.GetCurrentItsSites().ToList();
            IEnumerator<ItsSite> enSite = siteList.GetEnumerator();
            while (enSite.MoveNext())
            {
                using (ClsItsParking its = new     ClsItsParking(enSite.Current))
                {

                    List<ClsPbpRegistration> resultList;
                    //ClsPbpRegistration[] reglist = its.PbpRegistrationsBySite(enSite.Current).ToArray();
                    resultList = its.PbpRegistrationsBySite(enSite.Current);//***THIS Assignment causes the problem


                    if (resultList.Any())
                    {
                        using (Dt dtSite = new Dt(enSite.Current.ConnectionString))
                        {
                            // var result = dtSite.WriteItsPurchases(reglist);
                            var result = dtSite.WriteItsPurchases(resultList);
                            if (!result)
                                ClsLogger.WriteErrorLog("dt.WritePurchases returned false for site " + enSite.Current.CompanyName);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Sorry not much good at posting code.

dt.GetITSPurchases, GetCurrentItsSites signatures and PbpRegistrationBySite body

```
 public IEnumerable<ItsSite> GetCurrentItsSites()

 public ClsPbpRegistration[] GetItsPurchases(DateTime purchaseDate)


 public List<ClsPbpRegistration> PbpRegistrationsBySite(ItsSite site)
    {
        string regUrl = null;
        try
        {
            if (!Logon(site))
                ClsLogger.WriteErrorLog("ClsItsParking. Logon returned false");

            /**** Working Code*****/
            TimeSpan tWindow = new TimeSpan(0, TimeWindowMinutes, 0);
            DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now - tWindow;
            string startHour = startDate.Hour.ToString("00");
            string startMinute = startDate.Minute.ToString("00");

            DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;
            string endHour = endDate.Hour.ToString("00");
            string endMinute = endDate.Minute.ToString("00");

            string toDaysPurchases = "?searchFromDate=" + startDate.ToString(DateFormat) +
                               "&searchFromTimeHour=" + startHour + "&searchFromTimeMinute=" + startMinute + "&searchToDate=" + endDate.ToString(DateFormat)
                               + "&searchToTimeHour=" + endHour + "&searchToTimeMinute=" + endMinute + "&searchBy=modified";




            regUrl = site.UrlBase + site.RegistrationListExtension + toDaysPurchases;


            string registrationResponseString;
            registrationResponseString = HttpGetRequest(regUrl, Cookies, ItsUserAgent);
            {

                Logoff();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(registrationResponseString))
                {
                    XmlDocument motherShipRegistrations = new XmlDocument();

                    motherShipRegistrations.LoadXml(registrationResponseString);

                    //listRegistrations = GetNodeList(motherShipRegistrations);
                    //ClsPbpRegistration[] listRegistrations = GetRegistrationList(motherShipRegistrations);
                    //return null;
                    //return listRegistrations;
                    return GetRegistrationList(motherShipRegistrations);
                }


                return null;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            ClsLogger.WriteErrorLog("PbpRegistrationsBySite " + ex.Message + " Sent url was " + regUrl);
            return null;

        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the method `dt.GetCurrentItsSites()` return? IEnumerable?

Comment: Well what does `PbpRegistrationsBySite()` look like?

Comment: I've detected the same pattern with ANTS memory profiler, and the issue I have is using HttpClient as singleton object, the ConcurrentStack a member of a PinnableBufferClass used un SslStream in System.net.

In the long term, the memory usage grows and grows, the byte[] contained in this buffer class have a tendency to grow over time depite there are some garbage collections that reduce the  size.

i'm thinking of opening a ticket with Microsoft to validate if it's an issue and if there's a fix